# Kentico 9 Form creation

Tags: kentico

I'm building out a contact form, and for some reason I can only get the custom layout to render if the type is HTML. If I set it to ASCX, I get the Form Builder version.

I checked my setting against another Kentico based site, and can't see what I'm missing.

This is how it renders out. The `<fieldset>` tags are mine.

```html
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_pnlForm" class="FormPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_btnOK')">
  <fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <table class="EditingFormTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="FieldLabel">
          <label id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_lReasonForMessage" title="The user selects a reason, which also controls who gets the email notification" class="EditingFormLabel" for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_ctl01_fcReasonForMessage_dropDownList">Reason For Message:</label>
        </td>
        <td class="EditingFormValueCell">
          <div>
            <select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$plcZone$lt$cph_pageBody$mainSection$On_lineForm$viewBiz$ctl00$ctl01$fcReasonForMessage$dropDownList" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_ctl01_fcReasonForMessage_dropDownList"
            class="DropDownField form-control test">
              <option selected="selected" value="email1@test.com:Reason One">Reason One</option>
              <option value="email2@test.com:Reason Two">Reason Two</option>

            </select>
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_ctl01_fcReasonForMessage_autoComplete" class="autocomplete">


            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="FieldLabel">
          <label id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_lName" class="EditingFormLabel" for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_ctl04_fcName_txtText">Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td class="EditingFormValueCell">
          <div>
            <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$plcZone$lt$cph_pageBody$mainSection$On_lineForm$viewBiz$ctl00$ctl04$fcName$txtText" type="text" maxlength="200" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_ctl04_fcName_txtText"
            class="form-control">

          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="FieldLabel"></td>
        <td class="EditingFormValueCell">
          <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$plcZone$lt$cph_pageBody$mainSection$On_lineForm$viewBiz$ctl00$btnOK" value="Submit" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plcZone_lt_cph_pageBody_mainSection_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ctl00_btnOK"
          class="FormButton btn btn-primary">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in v9.0.32. Have you tried flushing the Kentico cache? Do you have the latest hotfix applied? Aren't you using an alternative form?

Comment: I'm stuck at hotfix 30 untill after launch. I'll try clearing the kentico cache and see, if not, it's the HTML alt form, which is tedious to code.

Comment: I don't see any bug fixed in HF 31/32 that would be relevant to this. This must be something else. Can you check what's stored in the database? And perhaps add a few screenshots describing the problem?

Comment: I will. I did clear kentico cache, tried a quick form using a new template, same thing. Let me try on my DEV VM, rather than my local dev machine, then start grabbing screen shots.

Comment: Same results on my DEV vm. Creating a test form, add one field. Create an ASCX layout, add the form via the form webpart. Rendered results are in a table, as per the auto generated form.

Comment: OK, I've been able to reproduce it. Let me check the latest hotfix.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to see i'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've tested with Kentico 9.0.44:

[image: Form design]

And the result is:

[image: Result form]

I also tried using ASPX markup like `<asp:Panel ID="pnlWrapper" runat="server"></asp:Panel>` but with no luck.
To me, it seems like a bug. I'd recommend to report it via the [bug submission form](http://devnet.kentico.com/support).

Comment: I have another Kentico site running hotfix 5, and it's fine. I'll submit a ticket and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Kentico hasn't been able to reproduce this. I think tomorrow i'll spin up a new local instance, apply the same hot fix and see.

Comment: @MarkHandy, any progress on this one?

Comment: No. Support said they couldn't duplicate it. I'm in the process of migrating to a new dev machine, but I built out the form with HTML, rather than the ASCX view. A bit clunky but it worked.

Comment: New kentico install on a new latptop, same issue. Back to support.